# Error while pressing Close Button in Dialog android

Tags: android, dialog

I have created my dialog when I press one of the menu buttons:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_first__window, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            About_us aboutus = new About_us(this);
            aboutus.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.close: System.exit(0); return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My Dialog layout

```
<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Close"
    android:onClick="ext_btn"/>
```

My Dialog Class

```
public class mydialog extends Dialog
{
    public About_us(Context context) {

        super(context);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_us);
    }

    public void ext_btn(View view) {

        About_us.this.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I Have tried a lot of codes to make the close button dismiss the dialog. 
My app always crashes. 
Where is the mistake ?

Comment: I have tried: 
system.exit(0);

Comment: use finish() instead of System.exit(0)

Comment: Used it already. It didn't work. When I press the back button it works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
 Button btn_ext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ext);
 btn_ext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
    }

});
```